# Combinatorics and Sticks

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ sticks lined up in a row and $k$ of them are to be chosen.

a) How many choices are there?

- There are $n \choose k$ choices or $nCk$

b) How many choices are there if no two of the chosen sticks can be consecutively?

- I think it's something like ${n-k+1} \choose k$   but I also think that whether there is an odd or even number of sticks matters... but I don't know how to show that.

c) How many choices are there if there must be at least $\ell$ sticks between each pair of chosen sticks?

Comment: WWhat is the difference between b) and c) ?

Comment: @miracle173: That was an ell in (c), not a one, though you had to look closely to tell; for clarity I’ve used $\ell$ in the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Your answer for b cannot be correct, as it is greater than the answer for a.  The restriction must reduce the number of choices.

Comment: Hint:  
Start with
"$a \; a \; a \; a \; a \; a \; a \; a $" Select three of the $a$ from the sequence, e.g. the second, the third and the fifth, and replace them by "$b\;c\;c\;c\;c$". You will get 
"$a \; b\;c\;c\;c\;c \; b\;c\;c\;c\;c \; a \; b\;c\;c\;c\;c \; a \; a \; a $". What is $n$, $k$ and $\ell$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Count the spaces between chosen sticks. Define $x_1$ to be the number of sticks before the first selected one, $x_2$ to be the number of sticks between the first and second selected ones, etc, and $x_{k+1}$ to be the number of sticks after the last selected stick.

Then $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{k+1} = n - k$. Your constraints turn into constraints on the variables, i.e. for a) $x_i \geq 0$ for all i, for b) $x_1,x_{k+1} \geq 0$ and $x_2,\dots,x_k \geq 1$, etc.

Can you solve it now? (The $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ should be useful...)

Answer (score 0):

For b), you can first line up $n-k$ dots, representing the sticks NOT chosen.
This leaves $n-k+1$ gaps, counting the gaps outside the first and last dots, and there are $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ of these gaps in which to put the chosen sticks. $\;\;\;\;$ (OR use the method below, with $l=1$.)

For c), you can line up $k$ dots representing the sticks to be chosen, and then remove $(k-1)l$ blockers to be inserted at the end.  This leaves $n-k-(k-1)l$ sticks, so the number of ways to arrange the $k$ dots and $n-k-(k-1)l$ sticks in order is $\binom{n-(k-1)l}{k}$, the number of ways to choose the k places for the dots out of the total of $n-(k-1)l$ places.  (Now insert the blockers between consecutive pairs of dots.)